# how to get return value as dropdownlist and how to assign it to other dropdownlist?

Tags: c#

I have two dropdownlist on my webpage i want to fill both of that dropdownlist with a single code written in a separate class file. i want to pass the table name with field name and want to get that data into my used dropdownlist.

my code is as follows

```
ddl1 = obj.Method("table_Name");
```

now the following function return the dropdownlist

```
public dropdownlist Method(string table_NAME)
{
          // code

        return dropdownlist_1;
}
```

now i want to use this code for filling multiple dropdownlist, by using this i can reduce my code. same code will be use to fill other dropdownlists also.

Please help me as soon as possible.............

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say separate class file, what programming language are you using to build your page (such as C# and ASP)?

Answer (score 0):

Please view if ObjectDataProvider is the class you are looking for. Here is the reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You would need a server side scripting language (such as PHP, Perl, JSP, ASP, Python, and many more). Once you have a language selected, the code for that should be relatively easy. The basic algorithm would be:

1. Issue an database request to get the data to fill in
2. Iterate over your results and generate a form option from each one
3. Concatenate the form options to one another
4. Insert the resulting menu into your page